# WebView load from file and from web

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I have a webview which will load from file or from the web. I set the `WebViewClient` to the webview and i override function `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`.

Everytime the webview loads and finished, it will go to the function `onPageFinished` no matter it loads from the file or from the web.

My question is, can i skip the `onPageFinished` (or any other function) in `WebViewClient` if it loads from the FILE, and still goes there if it loads from the WEB?

Thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to control execution of the onPageFinished() yourself. Check inside the method if url started from `"file:///..."` or `"http://..."`